# We take the equation : $(F): x^7 \equiv 2 (mod5)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We take the equation : $(F): x^7 \equiv 2 (mod5)$

Let be $x$ the solution of $(F)$

Prove that: $$x \wedge 5=1$$

I'm lost please give me a help

Comment: The notation

$$x \wedge 5$$

means what?

Comment: i have found only $x=3$

Comment: @quasi pgcd(x,5)

Comment: @quasi, or in English, just $\gcd (x, 5)$. It appears user281932 is a French speaker.

Comment: @user281932 - there are only 5 possible values of $x \mod 5$ so it is simple to test all of them. As Dr. Graubner has stated only $3$ solves the equivalence. $x$ itself can be any number of form $3 + 5n$, but all such numbers clearly have $gcd(x, 5) = 1$.